# sql query - insert

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the below sql script. When there is no record found by the select query there are no records inserted by the insert statement.
If no records found  by select query i want to have a record inserted with the new sequence numbers and other fields with null values. 
how can i do it.

```
insert into testing.test_ref_details(SEQNUM, TEST_TYPE,TEST_REF_NO)

select '&NEXT_SEQ_NO', '1',max(test_ref_no) as prev_test_ref1 
from    testing.test_runs_status
where   test_type = 1
and run_status = 1
and test_end_dt = (select last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate),-6))+2 from dual)
group by test_end_dt
```

;

Answer (score 3):

```
insert into testing.test_ref_details(SEQNUM, TEST_TYPE,TEST_REF_NO)
WITH q AS (
select '&NEXT_SEQ_NO' a, '1' b,max(test_ref_no) as prev_test_ref1 
from    testing.test_runs_status
where   test_type = 1
and run_status = 1
and test_end_dt = (select last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate),-6))+2 from dual)
group by test_end_dt
)
SELECT a, b, prev_test_ref1 FROM q
UNION ALL
SELECT '&NEXT_SEQ_NO', NULL, NULL FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM q);
```

Comment: Is using "WITH" has any constraints like oracle versions? version that is used is oracle10g

Comment: `WITH` works in 10g, e.g.: `create table t (a number); insert into t WITH q AS (select 1 a from dual) SELECT a FROM q;`

Comment: @Arav - The WITH clause (aka sub-query factoring, common table expressions) was introduced in Oracle 9i

Answer (score 2):

A PL/SQL solution:

```
begin
  insert into testing.test_ref_details(SEQNUM, TEST_TYPE,TEST_REF_NO)
  select '&NEXT_SEQ_NO', '1',max(test_ref_no) as prev_test_ref1 
  from    testing.test_runs_status
  where   test_type = 1
  and run_status = 1
  and test_end_dt = (select last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate),-6))+2 from dual)
  group by test_end_dt;

  if sql%rowcount = 0 then
    insert into testing.test_ref_details(SEQNUM)
    values ('&NEXT_SEQ_NO');
  end if;
end;
```